# Insert characters Into a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to turn the string `"125959"` into `"12:59:59"`.

Obviously, the string is the time so regular expressions aren't much good here.

Comment: How is your time `01:04:07` written??? `010407` or `147` ??

Comment: good question! 010407 :)

Comment: http://unstableme.blogspot.in/2009/09/insert-after-certain-characters-awk-and.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
time=125959
echo "${time:0:2}":"${time:2:2}":"${time:4:2}"
```

Answer (score 24):

I like `sed`:

```
time=125959
sed -e "s/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1:\2:\3/" <<< "$time"
```

- You can refine this by replacing `.` with `[[:digit:]]`
- Read about `<<<` (*Here strings*) in `man bash(1)`

Comment: If you're using GNU sed try `sed -e 's/../:&/2g' <<< "$time`