# How to insert text assigned to variable into a file before a string

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have:
A file called 'fooBar'.
A variable called 'myVar', which has the string 'the lazy' assigned to it.
I want to insert $myVar into the file fooBar before the text `'</dog>'`

fooBar Before:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over </dog>
```

fooBarAfter:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy </dog>
```

What is the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: You are saying you want it to insert `the lazy` when it hits the `<` or where? I just want to make sure the question is clear so it can be answered correctly

Comment: Refer to this link for bash string insertion:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230762/insert-characters-into-a-string-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
cat fooBar
The quick brown fox jumps over </dog>

myVar='the lazy'
sed -i.bak "s~</dog>~$myVar &~" fooBar

cat fooBar
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy </dog>
```